# Nunit: Error using UnitTestExtensions

Tags: vb.net, nunit

I get the following error when using xtunit with nunit. I want to use the rollback attribute from xtunit.
I m runnign nunit from the gui

```
Server stack trace:
at System.Data.Common.ITransactionExportFactory.Create(UInt32 DTCLength, Byte[] DTCAddr, ITransactionExport& export)
at System.Data.SqlClient.Transaction.CreateTransactionExport(Byte[] dtcAddr, UInt32 dtcLength, ITransaction transaction, ITransactionExport& transactionExport)
at System.Data.SqlClient.Transaction.GetTransactionCookie(Byte[] dtcAddr, ITransaction transaction, ITransactionExport& transactionExport, Byte[]& cookie, Int32& length)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNullDistributedTransaction(ITransaction transaction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistDistributedTransaction(ITransaction newTransaction, Guid newTransactionGuid)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistDistributedTransaction()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Activate(Boolean isInTransaction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
....

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
```

i have a base class which inherits from a base class

```
public class test
 Inherits TeamAgile.ApplicationBlocks.Interception.UnitTestExtensions.ExtensibleFixture
```